# Is there any performance benefit to using .net 4's no-PIA feature?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, pia, primary-interop-assembly

I understand that there's a deployment benefit to no-PIA, but is there a performance benefit to having the types embedded in the assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding this is a deployment feature.  You shouldn't see much of a performance difference.

There may be a slight improvement over the time it takes to load the PIA.